# I am trying to copy files from a server to my local directory using rsync.I don't want to copy the files which are copied earlier and being removed

Tags: rsync

I am trying to copy files from a server to my local directory using rsync.But after some times local files are being moved to archive.So, next time when I will copy the contents from the remote directory,I don't want to copy the files which are copied earlier.

I am using the below mentioned command

```
rsync -avhe ssh --progress cea@10.154.45.84:$RemoteFolderPath1 -t $LocalFolderPath1
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the update option (-u), quoting man page:           -u, --update                skip files that are newer on the receiver

Answer (score 1):

When you archive a file, append its name to a file, which I'll call `archived_files.txt`. Then use `--exclude-from=archived_files.txt` in your `rsync` command to skip those files.

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar for your valuable input . Your input will help me to implement the required logic .

Answer (score 0):

in [rsync man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) :

you can use:

```
--update                to update the existing files
--ignore-existing       skip updating files that exist on destination
```

the

```
--progress
```

that you used is for showing what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your input . Actually as I have mentioned earlier my local files after 5 mins will be moved to archive directory.But in the server it will exist for 3 days .Example : In sever location( RemoteFolderPath1 ) contains A,B files at 11 am.So,once I have copied A, B using rsync in LocalFolderPath1 and after 5 mins those files will be moved to archive.So,after 5 mins at 11.05am in the sever A, B will be there and C,D files will also be created.But this time I want to copy C,D only to the local folder not the earlier files(A, B). How can I achieve this functionality?